# Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'

Tags: vb.net, inicialização

Me dá o erro:

> O nome do campo ou da propriedade que está sendo inicializada em um inicializador de objetos deve começar com '.'.

```
 Private myImageList As System.Windows.Forms.ImageList = New ImageList()
    Private myImageListSmall As System.Windows.Forms.ImageList = New ImageList()
    Private myImageListLarge As System.Windows.Forms.ImageList = New ImageList()
    Private count As Integer = 0
    Private ofd As New OpenFileDialog() With { _
        Key .Multiselect = True, _
        Key .ValidateNames = True, _
        Key .Filter = "JPG|*jpg|JPEG|*.jpeg|PNG|*.png" _
    }
    Private fi As FileInfo
```

Comment: Você está no StackOverflow em **português**, traduza sua pergunta ou a realize no SOen

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam obrigado por avisar pois e a for;a de trabalhar com ingleses o tempo todo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este `Key` aí não faz o menor sentido, é só tirá-lo:

```
Private myImageList As System.Windows.Forms.ImageList = New ImageList()
Private myImageListSmall As System.Windows.Forms.ImageList = New ImageList()
Private myImageListLarge As System.Windows.Forms.ImageList = New ImageList()
Private count As Integer = 0
Private ofd As New OpenFileDialog() With { _
    .Multiselect = True, _
    .ValidateNames = True, _
    .Filter = "JPG|*jpg|JPEG|*.jpeg|PNG|*.png" _
}
Private fi As FileInfo
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/ObjectInitializer.vb).